# Noncommutative group schemes corresponding to quantum groups

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, noncommutative-algebra, group-schemes

I'm not an expert on quantum groups by any stretch, so forgive me if this question seems overly naive. That said, I was wondering if there is a way (or if there has been any attempt in the literature) to define a category of Drinfeld-Jimbo (DJ)-type quantum groups whose opposite category can be understood as a category whose objects are "noncommutative affine group schemes" of some kind (by "noncommutative", I mean in the ring-theoretic sense, not that the group schemes are nonabelian). My reason for asking this is that I've seen DJ-type quantum groups being described as noncommutative deformations of commutative Hopf algebras, and since these form a category that is dual to that of affine group schemes, perhaps DJ-type quantum groups also correspond to certain noncommutative geometric objects.